# Unable to log into website using requests.post despite matching network form data

Tags: python, authentication, post, web-scraping, python-requests

I am unable to login to a website using requests and fetch the API data behind an account. The requests payload data matches the form data used for normally logging in.

My code is as follows:

```
urlpage = 'https://speechanddebate.org/login'

header = {'User-Agent': 'Chrome/84.0.4147.89'}
payload = {'log': "email@gmail.com",
           'pwd': "password",
           'wp-submit': 'Log In',
           'rememberme': 'forever',
           'redirect_to': '/account',
           'testcookie': '1'}
session = requests.Session()
test = session.post(urlpage, headers = header, data = payload)
```

I used inspect element to find what data is sent via POST when I log in normally rather than through webscraping and it gives this result when I check under networking:

[image: Image of Network]

I am not sure what I am doing differently compared to the other StackOverFlow answers out there. Here's a  list of code modifications I've tried to make:

- Without sessions and just doing a normal request
- Making the data URL encoded
- Changing it and having a `with requests.Session() as session:` block instead of just
  `session = requests.Session()`
- And tried POST with headers and without headers etc.

When I login normally I get the status code 302 indicating that the login was successful and I've been transferred to another web page. However, when I do it through webscraping, it fails to login and returns status code 200 and returns it back to the login page.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
headers = {
    'authority': 'www.speechanddebate.org',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'origin': 'https://www.speechanddebate.org',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Mobile Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'referer': 'https://www.speechanddebate.org/login/',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
         }
```

Comment: Just tried, unfortunately, it doesn't work :( Still getting status code 200 and the session.get afterwards still returns the login page (indicating a failure to login) rather than the API pages that it should be on. Thanks tho!